# Access theme resources of another theme using code in Windows Phone Runtime 8.1 Apps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I know Windows Phone Runtime 8.1 have several `ThemeDictionaries` for different themes like Windows Runtime 8.

But it seems I can only access theme resource of the current using theme (maybe depends on `Application.RequestedTheme`?) with code like `Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"]`.

I can override `Default` theme in my `App.xaml` to override colors for all themes, but can I achieve it with code?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible. Windows 8.1 introduced optimized resource loading where the XAML parser only creates the resources when they're specifically requested ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.resourcedictionary.aspx)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theme resources in `Application.Resources` depends on `Application.RequestedTheme`.

But `FrameworkElement.Resources` depends on `FrameworkElement.RequestedTheme`.

So override resources from `(Window.Current.Content as FrameworkElement).Resources` will override current using theme resources (If no child elements overrides its `RequestedTheme`).